# How to install and configure xdebug in Linux Mint 18?

Tags: xdebug, php-7.0

I am using the *Netbeans IDE*, *PHP version 7.0* and I have already installed *Apache version 2.4.18* and *Linux Mint 18*.

I have also tried to install the debug files with

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xdebug
```

How can I proceed further?

Comment: Welcome! This looks like information you could find by doing a web search for documentation. If you have done a search, could you tell us if you are getting any error messages when trying to install or use xdebug?

Answer (score 2):

Download last stable release of **xdebug 2.6.0** :

```
wget -c "http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.6.0.tgz"
```

Extract file :

```
tar -xf xdebug-2.6.0.tgz

cd xdebug-2.6.0/
```

Build extension

```
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

after finshed compiling i found the binary on path;
  /usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so

for find **xdebug.so** use this comand :

```
pwd -L  xdebug
```

it print out : /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

**then go in directory /etc/php/7.0/mods-available and edit file as superuser  nano xdebug.ini file  add follows lines:**

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
  xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

`sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`  or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug

Comment: this was really helpful a lot but in the end my phpstorm failed to recognize the debugger file at all i have tried all the blogs for a fix but it has failed though this solution was helpful .